# Can't start a virtual machine with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. I installed VirtualBox but I have this message when I start it

[image: screenshot 1]

I executed `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms` and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`, and it says that they were already installed, but that message keeps showing when I run VirtualBox.

I created a virtual machine in VirtualBox, and when I want to start it, I get the following messages

[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]

Can someone tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: In the future, could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt purge virtualbox*`

Then run `sudo apt install virtualbox*`

Then finally `sudo modprobe vboxdrv`

it should work now.